# AutoMapper-ts mapped object is empty when I try to convert it to a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapping, automapper-3

I have the following class:

```
class testClass
{
    public text: string;
}
```

I create the following map using AutoMapper-ts:

```
AutoMapper.createMap('source', 'dest')
            .convertToType(testClass);
```

And then do my mapping:

```
this.newObject = AutoMapper.map('source', 'dest', this.anotherObjectWithSameProperties);
```

But `this.newObject` is always an empty `testClass` object.
If I remove the following line:

```
.convertToType(testClass);
```

Then the properties will be mapped to `this.newObject` as expected, but the type of `this.newObject` will be `Object` instead of `testClass`.

How can I map an object to another object using automapper-ts, but have the new object as the required type?

**UPDATE**

The AutoMapper-TS [documentation](https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/wiki/create-map-convert-to-type) show cases this method with a unit test but this unit test specifies the mapping explicitly:

```
.forMember('property', (opts: AutoMapperJs.IMemberConfigurationOptions) => { opts.mapFrom('ApiProperty'); })
```

If I do this with my `text` property like so:

```
AutoMapper.createMap('source', 'dest')
    .forMember('text', 'text');
    .convertToType(testClass);
```

then my implementation works as expected, but that defies the whole point of using automapper in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
class testClass
{
    public text: string;
}
```

to

```
class testClass
{
    public text: string='';
}
```

You need to initialize all properties in class

Comment: This works but why am I supposed to initialize all the variables? Makes no sense at all.

Answer (score -1):

you cast to the specified type after the map like so:

```
this.newObject = AutoMapper.map('source', 'dest', this.anotherObjectWithSameProperties) as testClass;
```

or

```
this.newObject = <testClass> AutoMapper.map('source', 'dest', this.anotherObjectWithSameProperties);
```

Comment: Nope. `this.newObject` is still an Object instead of `testClass`.